# Gnuplot load command doesn't find file in same directory

Tags: load, gnuplot

Here is the simple test file I'm trying to load:
file gnu2.b which contains:

```
    plot sin(x)
```

Results of calling gnu2.b:
in folder \progra~1\gnuplot\bin:
gnuplot # brings up gnuplot prompt, then I enter:

```
    load 'gnu2.b' # does the plot of sin(x), as expected, so the file is obviously found
```

But I need to do it in one line from the system command prompt:
C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin> # the system prompt

```
    gnuplot -e load 'gnu2.b' # what I want to do
```

RESULTS IN ERROR:

```
load
^
line 0: expecting filename -
```

same result if I use the full path for gnu2.b

But the file IS there: command

```
    'dir gnu2.b'
```

shows it as:

```
Directory of C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin
10/18/2023 04:41 PM 72 gnu2.b
1 File(s) 72 bytes
0 Dir(s) 882,727,567,360 bytes free
```

trying it omitting the -e: Doesn't work either

```
C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin>gnuplot load 'gnu2.b'
line 0: Cannot load input from ''gnu2.b''
^
"load" line 1: invalid command
```

All the book examples show similar commands working.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the comment to your question from yesterday? By the way, is it solved?
Check help `command-line-options`. See option `-c` for calling a script file.
Try:

```
gnuplot -p -c "C:\User\Test\Plotting\Test.gp"
```

Mind the double quotes not single quotes (at least under Windows). Both backslashes and foreslashes should work.

Comment: Yes, yesterday's problem is solved. Today's problem fails whether I use single or double quotes. Using -c instead of -e gives me the same error.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser! If I insert a null string before the unquoted file name, the command works properly! ie: gnuplot -persist -e ""  gnu2.b   So, I can get it to work, but have no idea why .

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: @user1067305 which gnuplot version you are working with? And which operating system? Windows I assume?

Comment: gnuplot 5.4 and Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Is gnu2.b in the C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin directory?

If you put C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin in your path using

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\gnuplot\bin
```

you should be able to do

```
gnuplot -p -e "load 'gnu2.b'"
```

from whatever directory gnu2.b is in.

Comment: By the way, you need both the double quotes and the single quotes